# Focus em um campo com tabpage

Tags: jquery

Estou utilizando este código, para colocar a bordar em vermelho quando um campo da tab não estiver sido preenchido corretamente, e ele então dá o focus na tab mais próxima, e assim sucessivamente.

```
$.each($('input[data-required="true"]'), function () {
        if (!this.value || this.value == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            var id = $($(this).parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
            $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Eu gostaria que desse `focus` no primeiro campo, para o usuário já digitar no campo. Tentei adicionando esta linha:

```
     $(this).focus();
```

Porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está bloqueando o evento `.focus()` de ser executado é o `e.preventDefault()`. 
Segue o código ajustado e funcionando:

```
    $.each($('input[data-required="true"]'), function () {
        if (!this.value || this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            var id = $($(this).parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
            $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
            $(this).focus();
            event.preventDefault(); // Vai prevenir o submit do formulário
            return false; // Vai parar a execução do .each() 
        }
    });
```